# Disable icon when selecting text

Tags: firefox

Whenever I select any text in Firefox this icon appears and it is very irritating:

[image]

I am using Firefox 21.0 on Windows XP.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: Smells like an extension.

Comment: What @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said. Disable all your extensions one by one to identify the culprit.

Comment: Or by halves, since that will likely be faster.

Comment: It's called Fastest Search: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastest-search/?src=search. Go into your extensions, find it and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into your extensions list: Firefox button -> Extensions.
2. Find the "Fastest Search" extension.
3. Disable it and restart if necessary.